# WebSocket (Sockjs and Stomp) with ServiceWorkers

Tags: html, websocket, stomp, sockjs, service-worker

I'm using Stomp and Sockjs to register a websocket with my Spring Boot self-contained server (3.1.1), which all works fine. However, I have implemented a ServiceWorker to handle offline services, which is all working, except for the socket. The call to ws://localhost/registerSocket yields this error on the frontend:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost/registerSocket/351/4vevdv79/websocket.

And this on the backend:

> ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null

In my ServiceWorker I've specifically excluded it from intercepting the ws request:

```
if (uri.indexOf("/registerSocket") === -1) {
   event.respondWith(getResponse(event));
}
```

Yet, inevitably the ws upgrade fails and it reverts to the old comet style polyfill.

Does anybody know of a way to get websockets working correctly with ServiceWorker?

Comment: I'm not sure if web sockets connections are intercepted by service workers, I think they aren't.

There's an error in your snippet though, `event.responseWith` should be `event.respondWith`.

Could you try adding some logging to the 'fetch' event and see if it's triggered when you open the web socket?

Comment: Yeah, it is. I've logged it extensively. I'm not sure it's supposed to intercept them though. According to some websites, it's only supposed to intercept http requests. Maybe this is just a bug in browsers' implementations?

Comment: I don't think so, could you share your source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found out about a bug in Firefox 44 that prevented Web Socket connections from working when a Service Worker was used.

See [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1243942).

The bug should be fixed now (since Firefox 44.0.1; it's even in the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0.1/releasenotes/)).

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` event handlers in a service worker are only [triggered in response to HTTP requests](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-global-scope-fetch-event). Requests to open a WebSocket or transmitting data over that WebSocket won't trigger the `fetch` event handler, meaning that the service worker won't get involved.

Comment: Thanks. Is your use of the future tense meant to convey that browsers' implementations may not conform to spec yet?

Comment: No, I didn't intend "will" to imply the future tense. I'll edit my response to clarify.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for clarifying. However. The fact remains that when I don't include a service worker and unregister it from about:serviceworkers, the ws upgrade goes through just fine. When I include the service worker, it fails. The only thing  I'm changing is the `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')` call.